# Multiple cases with the same instructions in Haskell

Tags: haskell

well this is my code:

```
fct 1 a b = a+b 
fct 3 a b = a+b
fct 8 a b = a+b
fct x a b = a-b  `for the rest : 2,4,5,6,7,9..16`
```

My question is, is there a way to combine the 3 first lines, as they do the same thing, something like "case x of" ? but with multiple values. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use guard syntax with different matching functions:

```
fct' x a b
  | x `elem` [1, 3, 8] = a + b
  | otherwise = a - b
```

Comment: you could also write it pointfree: `fct' x | elem x [1,3,8] = (+) ...`, but I admit this makes it less readable.

Comment: Thank you very much that was very helpful, yes the first is more readable